# Best practice to use @inject in mobx-react?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I know using @observer on more small components is good for the performance. Is it also reasonable to use @inject on as many as possible components ? Obviously, in this way it is easier to access the used props than passing through parent components. At the same time, it also becomes difficult to create presentational components. Nearly all components are directly connected to Mobx's stores. But even if we don't use @inject, components may still use @observer.

So my questions are:

1. How to create presentational components in Mobx? Or maybe there is no need for presentational components in Mobx.
2. What is the best practice to use @inject ? Or which components are reasonable to used with @inject?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Question1:**

You create presentational components the same way as in redux. Just give these components the props from outside and only use @observer on them.

There is no "need" to use presentational components. Even in Redux there is no need. It just depends on how you can reach your architectural goals/non-functional requirements.

You need to know and decide if you need presentational components without @observer. That could be the case when you for example want to reuse the presentational components in an application, that doesn't use mobx. Then you will run into problems when you have annotated every component with @observer.

**Question2:**

Use @inject and @observer on the container components and just pass the props down to your presentational components that are only annotated with @observer.

Comment: If I use `@inject` as many as possible , like the usage of `@observer`, do you think it would have some problems? Except that it is hard to reuse these components.

Comment: It is just an additional component that gets wrapped around the annotated component that passes down its props (stores) to the wrapped component. Could it be a performance issue? Maybe. But optimize that parts that are slow afterwards.